# How can I view more than one version of IE on my computer?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

Where I work we only have IE 7. I want to view  IE 6 on my computer also.

How can I view both on the same computer?

I want more than just a screen shot. I want to view both versions of IE as I write code.

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft makes available virtual machine images that can be used with the also free Virtual PC program for each version of IE to be used by testers. You can find these here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Comment: What happens after these VMs self-destruct?  Can they be redownloaded/reinstalled?

Answer (score 7):

You want [Multiple IE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE)... IE3 to 6 in one package!

Comment: Sometimes IE5, IE5.5 and IE6 crash unexpectedly. 
Multiple IE doesn't work on Windows Vista. Follow the progress of running Internet Explorer 6 natively on Windows Vista here!
Read the comments before asking questions. Most of the issues have been discussed below.

Sounds very buggy and lame.

Comment: ah! you beat me to it!  I use it all the time, it's great.  Since I do mainly web development, I use the Multiple IE, Firefox, Safari, and now Chrome when testing my sites.  Don't get upset if IE 5.5 or earlier doesn't work though, those are very far off the current standards.

Comment: I use it myself.  It works fine for me - a little unstable, but they always were a little unstable.  Question doesn't mention Vista.  Who wants to set up virtual machines just to install a browser?

Comment: Print preview doesn't work either.  And you can get into browser session confusion with IE7 and Multiple IE's IE6 running at the same time on the same PC.

Answer (score 5):

Try [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It supports IE5.5, IE6, IE7 and IE8 beta all in the one program.

Comment: IETester appears to be free from the bugs reported on Multiple IE.  Both are interesting test tools, though.

Comment: I've found it to be both stable and reliable in behaving as older versions of IE do on their own. Works just fine with Vista too.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use Multiple IE, but have found some limitations - it only handles the browser window display functionality, but it doesn't show you the print preview and has some other limitations.

So I suggest [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&DisplayLang=en).  It's free and you can find a [Win XP w/ IE6 image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) for free as well.

Answer (score 1):

While MultipleIEs works for most situations, it is best to run each version you need to support in a VM as it is supposed to be installed. This way you avoid some bugs in the standalone implementations such as problems with cookies, some forms being uneditable, conditional comments being a crap shoot, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a listing of different versions of IE, you can download and unzip: http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/32bit/standalone

I have a standalone version of IE6 in my Windows install that I just double click the IE6 executable and it runs smoothly.